# Solve the integral $\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac {x^2} {2t}}dx$

Tags: probability, integration, brownian-motion

To find the Variance of a Wiener Process, $Var[W(t)]$, I have to compute the integral
$$
Var[W(t)]=\dots=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac {x^2} {2t}}dx=\dots=t.
$$
I've tried integration by parts to solve the integral but end up with
$$
\dots=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}} \left(0 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac {x} {t} \cdot e^{-\frac {x^2} {2t}}\cdot \frac {x^3} 3 dx\right),
$$
which is even worse and probably wrong.

Can anyone please help me compute the first integral and show how it becomes equal to $t$?

(I know that the Variance for a Wiener Process (Standard Brownian motion)is defined as $t$ but want to prove it with the integral above.)

Comment: You could write (essentially, you have to include the $t$ dependence) $x^2e^{-x^2}$ as $x\cdot xe^{-x^2}$ and integrate by parts. If you are familiar with the [gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), you are done.

Comment: Try $u=x$ and do it by parts.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thanks. But assume it can be done without gaussian integral knowledge, of which I have none..

Comment: I still can't get it to work, any help appreciated..

Comment: I must go and sleep now. If you want, I could start within say 9 hours from now (it is 9:00pm here). So; if you are still concerned, post a comment for me and I shall try yo do my best. But it should very simple.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici, but I just got an answer (see below) so I think that should do it.

Comment: If you're in the probability context then you have essentially assumed $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2t} dx = \sqrt{2 \pi t}$, simply by virtue of writing the integral for the variance in the way that you have. This fact is the only "tricky" thing required (the rest is fairly easy integration by parts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can circumvent the integration if you observe that what you integrate is the pdf of a normal random variable times $x^2$.

---

Since you are already at Wiener processes, I assume that you can recognize a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). Can you see the pdf of a normal random variable inside your integral? To see this, write $$\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac {x^2} {2t}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \underbrace{\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}}e^{-\frac {x^2} {2t}}}_{density}dx=\mathbb E[X^2]$$ where $X$ is a random variable that is normally distributed with mean $μ=0$ and variance $σ^2=t$, i.e. its probability density function is $$f_X(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}}e^{-\frac {x^2} {2t}}$$ as it appears above. Therefore $$\mathbb E[X^2]=Var(X)+\mathbb E[X]^2=t-0^2=t$$

Comment: Woah, I never thought of this, thanks for showing it! Finding the Normal variance $σ^2=t$ was brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}\ dx $$ By symmetry of even function,  $$=2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}\ dx $$$$=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}\ dx $$
let $\frac{x^2}{2t}=u\implies \frac{x}{t}\ dx=du$ or $dx=\frac{t}{\sqrt{2tu}}\ du=\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}}\frac{ du}{\sqrt u}$, 
$$=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t}}\int_{0}^{\infty}(2tu)e^{-u} \sqrt{\frac{t}{2}}\frac{ du}{\sqrt u}$$
$$=\frac{2t}{\sqrt {\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{1/2}e^{-u}\ du$$
using Laplace transform: $\color{blue}{\int_0^{\infty}t^ne^{-st}\ dt=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}}}$, 
$$=\frac{2t}{\sqrt {\pi}}\left[\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{s^{1+\frac{1}{2}}}\right]_{s=1}$$
$$=\frac{2t}{\sqrt {\pi}}\left[\frac{\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(1)^{3/2}}\right]$$
$$=\frac{2t}{\sqrt {\pi}}\left[\frac{1}{2}\sqrt \pi\right]=\color{red}{t}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $a=\dfrac1{2t}.~$ Then we are left with evaluating $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-ax^2}~dx.~$ But the latter can be written as $-\dfrac d{da}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}~dx.~$ [Can you take it from here ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) ;-$)$

Comment: Yes, I think so, thanks. By integrating by parts we get $$\dots=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}}\left(0-\dfrac d{da}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}~dx \right)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {2 \pi t}}\cdot \frac {\sqrt{\pi}} {2 \sqrt{\frac 1 {2t}}^3}=\sqrt{\frac 1 t} \cdot t^{3/2}=[t>0]=t$$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this integral is probably set t=1/u, then the function inside the integral is the derivative of the Gaussian density with respect to u.  After swapping integration and partial derivative (this is physics, so we don't need to prove that this is allowed) the remaining work is trivial.

If all you need is the solution, it is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions

Answer (score 2):

Since $t>0$, you can do the substitution
$$
x=u\sqrt{2t}
$$
that brings the integral into
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2tu^2e^{-u^2}\sqrt{2t}\,du
=\frac{t}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u\cdot 2ue^{-u^2}\,du
$$
Now integrate by parts with $u$ as finite part and $2ue^{-u^2}$ as differential part:
$$
=\frac{t}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\Bigl[-ue^{-u^2}\Bigr]_{-\infty}^{\infty}
+\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du\right)
$$
The first part is $0$, the second is known to yield $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, especially about the integration by parts and clearly showing which is finite vs differential! I took the Gaussian integral on the second one, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx =\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: @litmus For integration by parts to work you need to take as differential factor a function which you can write an antiderivative of.